# why do my changes to the dom not show up until after function has run

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

my `eval()` call is fairly intensive and takes about a second to generate each solution.

Therefore it takes about a second to generate each paragraph element (which I then append to the dom - `document.getElementById('project_euler_solutions').appendChild(p);`  ).

Therefore I expected each paragraph to appear on the webpage about a second apart. (so after about 40 seconds I would have 40 paragraphs say).

However, when I click the button, Nothing happens for 40 seconds, and then all the solutions appear at once.

**How come it waits for all of them to finish before it updates the dom?**

**I thought each paragraph would appear as soon as it was appended to the dom**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <script src="http://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-1.6.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/statics/project_euler.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("button").click(function(){
                for (var i in window) {
                    if (i.slice(0,5) == "solve") {
                        var p = document.createElement('p');
                        p.innerHTML = "running: " + i;
                        document.getElementById('project_euler_solutions').appendChild(p);
                        var p = document.createElement('p');
                        p.innerHTML = "Solution: " + eval(i + "()");
                        document.getElementById('project_euler_solutions').appendChild(p);
                    }
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="project_euler_solutions"><button>Calculate solutions</button></button></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Javascript runs in the same thread as UI, so you need to give the control back for the DOM to re-draw all the changes.

Comment: This makes sense.. How do you suggest I give control back to the DOM? I have found this post ( http://www.kryogenix.org/days/2009/07/03/not-blocking-the-ui-in-tight-javascript-loops ) which suggests use of setTimeOut()

Comment: @robert king: yep, `setTimeout` is a common practice. So you split your big task to a smaller tasks, and each one runs the next one in delay manner

Answer (score 1):

Force a reflow:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("button").click(function(){
            for (var i in window) {
                if (i.slice(0,5) == "solve") {
                    var p = document.createElement('p');
                    p.innerHTML = "running: " + i;
                    document.getElementById('project_euler_solutions').appendChild(p);
                    var p = document.createElement('p');
                    p.innerHTML = "Solution: " + eval(i + "()");
                    document.getElementById('project_euler_solutions').appendChild(p);
                    document.getElementById('project_euler_solutions').offsetHeight; //Force a reflow
                }
            }
        });
    });
```

You can also setTimeout between the drawings:

```
    var keys = Object.keys(window).filter(function(i){
        return i.slice(0,5) === "solve";
    });

    (function (i){
        (function k(){
            var p = document.createElement('p');
            p.innerHTML = "running: " + keys[i];
            document.getElementById('project_euler_solutions').appendChild(p);
            var p = document.createElement('p');
            p.innerHTML = "Solution: " + eval(keys[i] + "()");
            document.getElementById('project_euler_solutions').appendChild(p);
            if( i++ < keys.length - 1 ) {
                setTimeout(k, 0);
            }            
        })()
    })(0)
```

Comment: I added the line "document.getElementById('project_euler_solutions').offsetHeight;" but it doesn't seem to have any effect..?

Comment: @robertking I guess then you have to setTimeout between the loops, I'll add code for that

Comment: Thanks, I changed keys.length to keys.length-1 and it works perfectly.

Comment: Also, .filter() isn't available on my cellphone's browser so I had to modify that bit of code.